# Как передать глобальную переменную для всех view в Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте. 
Не знаю как создать переменную, которая будет видна во всех blade шаблонах.Пример `{{$btc}}` должна быть видна не только в `home.blade.php`, но и в `exemple.blade,php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще одним из вариантов решения может быть использование

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: можете дать пример кода, просто я искал искал и не нашол, как правильно использовать, и у меня тут выдают FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Providers\View'

Comment: Пример кода дан по ссылке. Вы не забыли в начале файла указать `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего вам нужен Сomposer. Все описано в документации:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Коротко:

1. Добавляем в загрузку путь до Composer и путь до View в Providers:

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class MyComposerProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       public function boot()
       {
           view()->composer(['layouts.main'], 'App\Http\Controllers\Composer');
       }

   }
   ```
2. Создаем Composer:

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   class Composer
   {
       public function compose($view)
       {
           $GLOBAL_VAR = 'Hello, world!';
           $view->with('GLOBAL_VAR', $GLOBAL_VAR);
       }
   }
   ```
3. В /config/app.php в массив 'providers' добавляем:

> App\Providers\MyComposerProvider::class,

4. Теперь для views/layouts/main.blade.php и все зависящие имеют доступ к $GLOBAL_VAR.